# Download file failed

Tags: python-3.x, python-requests, cloudflare

i want to downlowd a file but its success on the other hand on idm i can downlowd the .srt file

the link is :
url = 'https://my-subs.co/download/film-17227.srt'

```
import requests
import requests, re
LINKFILE='/tmp/link'

url='https://my-subs.co/download/film-17227.srt'
HDR= {'User-Agent':'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; rv:85.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/85.0',
      'Accept': 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8',
      'Accept-Language': 'fr,fr-FR;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.5,en;q=0.3',
      'Host': 'my-subs.co',
      'Referer': 'https://my-subs.co/downloawd/sJWVwwSCMRW4qsjEpgNwjE20Ad.L42Q63B1ZZ4Zu5v4G0Vsj4ANlGEF6l99bxa4ARevuSPgjCHL4RiyDU6Gxbyp15T7A    a7tYNd0qZLUIh_KtUj_kMVnJm8osrjHINK9pBzKMeVlmAzbcTBh08S.kjQ--',
      'Upgrade-Insecure-Requests': '1',
      'Connection': 'keep-alive',
      'Accept-Encoding':'gzip, deflate'}



  
s = requests.Session()  

def geturl():
    data = s.get(url,headers=HDR,verify=False).text
    print(data)
    with open(LINKFILE, "a") as f: f.write(data)
geturl()
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.